# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity when trying to save POJO

Tags: exception, mapping, entity, pojo

I get the below error when I invoke the method to save an entity to the database.

```
ERROR: org.aggu.sramam.exceptions.SramamException - Exception thrown:
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.aggu.sramam.pojo.SramaSangham
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1096)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1443
```

The POJO object is there in the package, and I also have the below entry in my hibernate-cfg.xml file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<!--  List out the entities (i.e POJO linked to DB table) here -->
<session-factory>
<mapping class="org.aggu.sramam.pojo.SramaSangham" />
</session-factory>     
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below is the entry in the servlet-config.xml file, which gives the code base links

```
<!-- The below is the base package for all Sramam apps -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.aggu.sramam" />
```

What have I missed here? I have added the @Entity, @Table, @Id tags etc. in the POJO object. There is an Unqiue ID column (Primary key), but I have not written any explicit code to generate the ID automatically. Would that be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Figured this out myself. The issue was that in my servlet-context.xml file, I had NOT given a reference/link to the hibernate.cfg.xml. Once this was given, the error got resolved and records started getting inserted.

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
<beans:props>
<beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
<beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>
<beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
</beans:props>
</beans:property>
**<!- This line did the trick -->
<beans:property name="configLocation">
<beans:value>WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
</beans:property>**
</beans:bean>
```